# getting an object data inside an object in java

Tags: java, object

i have a x object that contains a object inside , and i would like to acess it from a method without extra write code.
Let's say this is my object :

```
{
    "status": "Success",
    "code": "200 OK",
    "message": "OK",
    "data": {
        "renter": {
            ....some Hashmap information.......
        }
    }
}
```

lets say i want to access the information the object renter inside the object data brings .
For that

in my method Y i did this :

```
 @Override
    public Y methodY(String userName) throws Exception{
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        Map<String,Object> clienteFeignOnMap=  client.findByRenterName(userName);

        //////////ACCESSING THE OBJECT DATA//////////////////
        Map<String,Object> objectResponseData= (Map<String, Object>) clienteFeignOnMap.get("data");

        //////////ACCESSING THE OBJECT RENTER INSIDE DATA FOR DESERIALIZING TO TyPE RENTER//////////////////
        Renter renter = mapper.convertValue(objectResponseData.get("renter"), new TypeReference<Renter>(){ });
......more code.............
    }
```

This way is successful and works, but still i think i could find a better option that allows me on one line  resume that access from the inner object renter .

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestion. Happy ne year 2021

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create a Java class to map the attributes as @Migwel suggested and want to use `java.util.Map`, then you may have to use Apache BeanUtils or something equivalent to get to deep elements.

```
BeanUtils.getNestedProperty( map, elementPath )
```

where `elementPath` is a dot separated path to the element. `data.renter`, in your case.

`PropertyUtils.getNestedProperty( map, elementPath )` also does the same thing.

However, these will not let you access indexed properties, in case you have arrays within the objects. For that, as far as I know, you will have to write custom code akin to the method below.

```
public static <T> T getMapElement( Map<String, ? super Object> map, String path ) {
    if( isEmpty( path ) ) return null;
    
    String[] parts = path.split( "[\\[\\]\\.]" );
    
    Object currElem = null;
    try{
        currElem = map;
        for( int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++ ){
            String part = parts[ i ];
            boolean done = false;
            
            /* Handle List. */
            if( currElem instanceof List ) {
                int index = integer( part, -1 );
                if( index >= 0 ) {
                    currElem = ( (List) currElem ).get( index );
                    done = true;
                }
            }
            
            if( done ) continue;
            
            /* Handle Map. */
            if( currElem instanceof Map ) currElem = ( (Map) currElem ).get( part );
            
            if( currElem == null ) break;
        };
    }
    catch( Exception e ){}
    
    return (T) currElem;
}
```

---

### Edit

There is also `json-path` from group `com.jayway.jsonpath` that also allows one to inspect a JSON directly into deep elements. Disclaimer: I haven't used and am not sure what it uses to deserialize the JSON. However, it may be worth a research.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using maps, you should create proper objects.

For example:

```
public class Response {
    private String status;
    private String code;
    private String message;
    private Data data;
    // constructor, getters, setters
    ...
}
```

And so on with a class `Data` and a class `Renter`, etc.

Then, when using objectMapper, you can directly deserialize it into your Response object